# Speeding up data processing with Dask

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dask

I need to read 7.2M files from an S3 bucket and do a simple data processing (filtering). For the data processing, I'm using Dask. I'm wondering how I can speed up the process.

**Note that I use a machine with 64 processors and 500GB RAM.**

Here's my code:

```
s3_path = 's3://some_bucket_name/*.csv'

df = dd.read_csv(s3_path, storage_options = {'key': key, 'secret': secret})

df = df[df['some_column'].isin(some_list)]
    
df.to_parquet('s3://some_bucket_name/some_folder_name/', 
                  storage_options = {'key': key, 'secret': secret}, write_index=False)

df = dd.read_parquet(f's3://some_bucket_name/some_folder_name/',
               storage_options = {'key': key, 'secret': secret})

df = df.compute()
```

Comment: I would definitely strongly recommend against csvs for something this large. can you use parquet?

Comment: oh - also definitely don't call compute before writing. just write the outputs - that will allow dask to clear memory as it writes the output.

Comment: After filtering, the data-frame should be much smaller. The files are already CSV.

Comment: What should be the npartitions? That is, df = df.repartition(npartitions=64)

Comment: yeah - but I highly recommend writing to parquet. csv doesn't store any type information, so you're doing a ton of extra work to decide whether a column full of string numbers (everything in a csv is a string) should be strings, floats, ints, datetimes, etc. if you're reading in a parquet file that's all part of the spec and you go straight from binary on disk to the in-memory numpy array. I would reommend avoiding repartitioning if at all possible. just read it in, filter, and save to parquet.

Comment: if the filtered outputs are much, much smaller, then I'd probably recommend doing the above as a first pass, then reading it back in and doing a repartition only job. but the I/O and the sheer number of tasks is what's going to kill you on the first pass, so avoiding complexity at all costs is what I'd recommend. you might even need to write this in pandas and then map groups of files to workers with dask.distributed's `client.map` just to reduce scheduler burden.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I edited the code, could you please see now? Is that what you mean?

Comment: sure. if the outputs are small enough to fit into memory then you could compute it directly - sorry I thought this was a larger-than-memory to larger-than-memory op

Comment: So how fast is this, and what were you hoping for?

Comment: Please try a LocalCluster with dask-distributed, which will give you better memory watching and parallelise somewhat better over CPU-bound operations. Worth a comparison.